Ошибка Unresolved reference: R
Здравствуй, я полнейший ноль в андроид студио, но вот возникла проблема, студия выдает ошибку, но я не понимаю в чем именно, код работал в проекте, где я писал, но когда я закинул файлы в проетк на гит, то они стали выдавать эту ошибку
package com.example.app

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val userLogin:EditText=findViewById(R.id.user_login)
        val userEmail:EditText=findViewById(R.id.user_email)
        val userPassword:EditText=findViewById(R.id.user_password)
        val button:Button=findViewById(R.id.button_reg)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val login=userLogin.text.toString().trim()
            val email=userEmail.text.toString().trim()
            val password=userPassword.text.toString().trim()


            if (login==""||email==""||password=="")
                Toast.makeText(this,"Не все поля заполнены",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else{
                val user=User(login,email,password)
            }
       }
   }

}

Судя поду и ошибке, у вас R не определена

Наверное вы изменили свойство namespace в gradle-скрипте, в результате чего класс R оказался в другом пакете и теперь его необходимо импортировать, то есть добавить в список импортов строку: import  <namespace>.R, где  - то, что указано в build.gradle
